# "InetAddress" don't work in Android but it works in netbeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans

Goal:
Use host adress using InetAddress.

Problem:
Why does the code not working in android studio? The same syntax code works at at netbeans.

What part am I missing?

Thank you!

Info:
*I'm new in android
*I'm using API 23
*I also have tried "getByName" but it doesn't work

[image]

### [image]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jfdimarzio.test1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

---

MainActivity.java

```
package com.jfdimarzio.test1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

---

Client.java

```
package com.jfdimarzio.test1;

import java.net.InetAddress;


public class Client
{

    private static final int PORT = 2001;
    private static final String DEFAULT_HOST = "www.google.com";

    public void test()
    {

        java.net.InetAddress addr;
        addr = InetAddress.getAllByName(DEFAULT_HOST);

    }
}
```

---

Comment: you can either catch or add throws clause to handle the exception

Comment: Did You convert your eclipse code to AndroidStudio?

Comment: Try changing ´ InetAddress.getAllByName(DEFAULT_HOST);´ to ´addr = InetAddress.getByName(DEFAULT_HOST);´

Comment: I did not change the eclipse code to andriod studio

Comment: I gave a change to change it into "getByName" but the same problem occur

Comment: "you can either catch or add throws clause to handle the exception" it doesn't work because the code I have now cannot build the project due to the error message.

Comment: Oh, so You cannot even covert it to gradle, I see...